# How can i save changed CSS in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I just started editing my website's CSS in Chrome's Developer Console. I went too far without realizing and now I am liking the design I just made and don't want to lose all the style changes in the made as soon as I refresh the page or close Chrome.

The changes are going to be erased as soon as I refresh the code so I want to download the new Custom.css file (edited version).

Is there any method to do this?

Comment: just hit control save when editing the file in the sources view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't actually download it, but you van get the code. While looking at the Elements tab, you should see your CSS under "Styles."  In the "Styles" window, it should name the CSS file that each style comes from. Presumably, in your case that would be Custom.css.  If you click on where it says Custom.css, it should open on the "Sources" tab with a tab containing the content of your CSS file.  From there you can just copy and paste it.  Not super neat, but you won't lose your changes.